# Getting errors when running Rails server with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

```
dani@saeedi:~/Desktop/website/myweb$ rails server
/home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': libmysqlclient.so.20: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.5/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `each'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `block in require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.1/lib/bundler.rb:108:in `require'
    from /home/dani/Desktop/website/myweb/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/Desktop/website/myweb/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/dani/Desktop/website/myweb/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/dani/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /home/dani/Desktop/website/myweb/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` from terminal

Comment: Pro-tips for posting: (1) format your console output and log files, there's a button to do so in the editor; (2) an error dump with no context except for a title doesn't looks like a great effort has been made, and is likely to attract downvotes, (3) readers know you need help, so "please help me" will generally just be understood as begging, (4) show us what research you did to fix the problem. Did you search for the error?

Comment: [Plenty of duplicates here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails+libmysqlclient.so.20%3A+cannot+open+shared+object+file%3A+No+such+file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably libmysqlclient is not installed in your system. Install it by using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Cheers!